# Hyperlinks not working when menu changes to suit smaller screen size

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

The menu for my website changes when the screen size gets smaller to suit the different devices.

All links are working on the full menu. However, when the menu changes to suit a smaller device, the links in the dropdown of the menu cannot be clicked but the link is there as when I open it in a new tab, it is going to the correct place.

I am assuming that maybe I have something in my CSS that is blocking it from working.

The website is [privateinvestigator-wrexham.co.uk](https://privateinvestigator-wrexham.co.uk/)

I have Googled to try and find advice. However, I cannot seem to find many articles. There was a question on Stack Overflow that was the same, and the answer suggested padding overlapping, but it doesn't look like I have any padding overlapping.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="accordion-mobileContainer">
<div class="accordion-mobile">
<dl>
<dt><a class="accordion-mobileTitle">Matrimonial</a></dt>
<dd class="accordion-mobileItem accordion-mobileItemCollapsed">
<div  class="accordion-mobileContent">
<ul style="margin-bottom:0px;">
<li><a href="/surveillance-in-wrexham/matrimonial-surveillance-in-wrexham/">- Matrimonial Surveillance</a></li>
<li><a href="/investigations-in-wrexham/matrimonial-investigations-in-wrexham/">- Matrimonial Investigations</a></li>
<li><a href="/investigations-in-wrexham/proof-of-cohabitation-investigations-in-wrexham/">- Proof of Cohabitation</a></li>
<li><a href="/investigations-in-wrexham/background-check-investigations-in-wrexham/partner-background-check-investigations/">- Partner Background Checks</a></li>
<li><a href="/lie-detector-test-in-wrexham/matrimonial-lie-detector-test-in-wrexham/">- Matrimonial Lie Detector Tests</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</dd>
</dl>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well one reason it's not working compared to when on desktop is because they are completely different elements. It is still surprising that the mobile links aren't working though. My guess is it has to do with `JavaScript` though. I would add some of your code here so we can see what how the mobile drop down works.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I have added the html for one of the dropdown sections to the original question.

Comment: When I inspected the drop down element, in the desktop mode each anchor (a) element had an href attribute but in the drop down elements in the narrow viewport menu there are no such attributes so no wonder the links aren't working.

Comment: @AHaworth I don't see what you're talking about. I also inspected it, but I saw href attributes, and I even tested the links in each href. They work correctly from there.

Comment: Ah, I see, I  was assuming that as Matrimonial was in an anchor element that that would have an href. Apologies, was looking at the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your HTML, the problem is that you have a script on your site (https://privateinvestigator-wrexham.co.uk/cdn-cgi/scripts/7d0fa10a/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js, note: this link might change overtime) with the following code snippet (although it might not look it, as it is minified):

```
$('.accordion-mobile').click(function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
```

`preventDefault()` here is likely the cause of your headache. [It prevents the default behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) of elements, like `<a>` opening a link. Therefore, all links within the `.accordion-mobile` element won't work.

To fix this, either modify the code above (that would be my suggestion), or [manually navigate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href) to the clicked page instead.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It seems that it is not that script that is causing the error. That script is generated from a Cloudflare setting, so I tested turning it off but the problem is still there.

Comment: NP! Are you sure it wasn't still cached or something? You can check by inspecting the .accordion-mobile and clicking the event button next to it in the HTML. Another thing you could check is if something invisible is overlapping with the content, cookiebanners and popups tend to do stuff like that